# Instruct constructor method to use default value if null

Tags: c#, design-patterns, default-value

I'm designing an API wrapper with a constructor something like this:

```
public class Client(string username, string password, int timeout = 60)
```

The caller looks like this:

```
class Program 
{
    private static int? Timeout => GetFromConfig("Timeout");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client(Username, Password, Timeout);
        // do things...
    }
}
```

I would like to use Client's default timeout (60) if Timeout is null.

I know of a few options:

**1) Use conditional logic in Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Timeout == null) 
    {
        Client client = new Client(Username, Password);
    }
    else 
    {
        Client client = new Client(Username, Password, Timeout);
    }
}
```

I dislike this solution because 1) it's a lot of code, and 2) the code grows exponentially as I add conditional parameters (e.g. if I added `int MaxFailedRequests = 5` to Client()'s signature, my if/else block grows to 4 blocks).

**2) Handle null values in Client()**

```
public class Client(string username, string password, int? timeout) 
{
    _timeout = timeout ?? 60;
}
```

I dislike this solution, because the default value is no longer exposed in the constructor's signature (which acts as excellent/free documentation).

**3) Handle null values in Client() with a default value**

```
public class Client(string username, string password, int? timeout = 60) 
{
    _timeout = timeout ?? 60;
}
```

I dislike this solution because 1) it's not immediately obvious how null will be handled (requires more documentation), and 2) the default value is duplicated (it would stink if someone modified one but forgot to modify the other).

**4) Use null operator and `usedefaultparam` keyword in Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Client client = new Client(Username, Password, Timeout ?? usedefaultparam);
    // ...
}
```

I like this solution because it's easy to read and grows nicely if I add more optional parameters.

I dislike it because the `usedefaultparam` keyword doesn't seem to exist.

**Thus my question:**

Does something like option 4 exist? If not, is there a nicer, fifth pattern I am not thinking of?

Comment: how about `public class Client(string username, string password, int? timeout = null)` ?

Comment: In 4), where is the Main method supposed to get the value of `usedefaultparam` from?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that's a pretty good solution, but the default value of `timeout` still has to be documented outside the constructor's signature, which isn't ideal.

Comment: @mm8 I'm thinking of `usedefaultparam` as more a keyword than a variable. It would be a value meaning "the called method MUST use the default value for the parameter", i.e. functionally the same as not providing a value at all.

Comment: @mac9416: Sorry, that doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @mm8 it doesn't make sense as a way to approach the problem, or my phrasing doesn't make sense? Maybe this will help: the `default` keyword came to mind, because it's interpreted as "the default value for the some type". This (probably non-existent) keyword would just be interpreted as "the default value for this parameter".

Comment: If you want the default value you either provide it or leave the parameter out.

Comment: @mm8 sure. But that pattern results in the problems mentioned under #1. I think this keyword would be nice syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caller is either supposed to provide a value for the timeout parameter or use the default one that is defined in the `Client` class' constructor.

If you want to be able to use the default value that you define in the `Client` class in the caller class, you should expose it from the `Client` class. You could for example do this using constant:

```
public class Client
{
    public const int DefaultTimeout = 60;

    public Client(string username, string password, int timeout = DefaultTimeout)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Caller:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Client client = new Client(Username, Password, Timeout ?? Client.DefaultTimeout);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I really like that. I guess the disadvantages would be 1) an extra line of code, 2) having to know `Client` has a default value field, and 3) *maybe* the value of DefaultTimeout is less readily visible in your IDE. But those are tiny disadvantages. I'll probably accept this if no magical better solution arises.